# How to get different implementation of top level function in Unit and instrumentationTests for Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-testing

I have a kotlin file with top level function(not member of any class). It compiles to class with static function in Java.
I want to have different implementation of this function for unit tests (platform independent) and instrumentation tests (production behaviour + Espresso Idling Resource).
I can put the same file to the same path for prod and tests, but when I put it to test and androidTest - IDE see it as in one source set and cannot resolve which function I would like to use.
Since I'm using top level functions, I cannot use DI to pass different implementation to tested class.

Is there any was to have different implementation of the class for test and androidTest for top level functions?

I tried

```
sourceSets {
androidTest {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
    java.exclude('src/test/java/util/CoroutinesUi.kt')
}
test {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
}
}
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem for now by creating object delegate, that gets implementation, and my top level function just calls currently available implementation from this delegate.
In that case I have to just reset implementations in @Before in base test, but getting few virtual calls, which is OK.